# What type of bifurcation occurs from the transition from a saddle to a center

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, parametric, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

If I have a system that takes the form
$\dot x =by$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\dot y = y^2 + x$,
I get a Jacobian matrix at the origina of the form

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & b & \\
        1 & 0 & \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

We see that $\tau$ = 0 and $\Delta$=-$b$
This means that that eigenvalues $\lambda$ = $\pm$$\sqrt b$.
As the value $b$ passes through 0 the behavior around the origin goes from a center to a saddle.

What kind of bifurcation is this called?

Comment: Warning: purely imaginary eigenvalues do not imply that a *nonlinear* ODE has a center, in general. In this case you do, but that's not a sufficient condition.

Comment: I know but in this I'm simply looking for how to classify a change from a center to a saddle. Would you know?

Comment: Not a typical bifurcation. At $b=0$ you have continuum of equilibria close to the origin, so it's degenerate situation. What kind of characterization/classification do you want? It could be a [Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bogdanov-Takens_bifurcation) would it be not so degenerate.