# Type of bifurcation when a saddle point collides with a center

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

Consider the following first-order autonomous system
$$
\begin{align}
&\dot{x}=y,\\
&\dot{y}=-x^2+\mu,
\end{align}
$$
where $\mu$ is a parameter. When $\mu>0$, the system has two equilibrium points $x_1=\sqrt{\mu}$ and $x_2=-\sqrt{\mu}$. By considering the linearization the system around the equilibrium points, it is easy to check that $x_1$ is a center, while $x_2$ is a saddle point. The two equlibrium points collide at the bifurcation point $\mu=0$ and then disappear. What is this type of bifurcation called? It seems that this bifurcation is similar to the [saddle-node bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle-node_bifurcation), but not exactly the same. Can anyone give some references?

Here is a similar question: [What type of bifurcation occurs from the transition from a saddle to a center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016144/what-type-of-bifurcation-occurs-from-the-transition-from-a-saddle-to-a-center)